# Why Android Studio 2.0 doesnt support Perforce?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle, perforce

Recently Android Studio 2.0 was released which was based on Intellij 15. I15 has support was perforce but strangely I couldn't find the option on my Android Studio 2.0. Is there anything I am missing like p4Client or .p4Config etc?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that's not through a plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending Commonsware's answer the integration of perforce with intellij or android studio is through a plugin. [Perforce Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7685?pr=).

**NOTE:** Its available in Android Studio and no premium/ultimate editions required.

[Instructions how to install plugin in Intelliji/Android Studio](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/enabling-and-disabling-plugins.html?search=plugin)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perforce is supported in the commercial IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition, while Android Studio is based on open-source IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition. You can purchase Ultimate Edition, which includes Android Studio functionality.